# How to determine time of dephasing?

Tags: mathematical-physics, oscillators

Let's assume that I have an oscillating value A. After some time the oscillations are being damped so the diagram of A is like on the picture below:

[image]

Now how to determine when does the A is reduced by half? I want to characterize this decay, but with several values equal to the 1/2 of the initial A I don't know how to point at correct "half-life".

To sum up: What is the best mathematical way to characterize oscillating decay?

Comment: Normally you'd model the data as $\text{env}(t) \cos(\omega t)$ where $\omega$ is the oscillation frequency and $\text{env}(t)$ is an envelope. If you were to e.g. fit to that function, you would then define the decay in terms of $\text{env}(t)$.

Comment: @DanielSank but I have only numeric data.'

Comment: So what? Can you not fit it? Why not post the actual data instead of the cartoon?